# Trying to execute a React project

Tags: reactjs

I just started using React and have a project I'm trying to run on replit. The code tries to import react-doc-viewer. I went to packages and the package @chalkbooks/react-doc-viewer@^1.15.0 is listed as an installed package. How do I get my project to use that package? Thanks. This is the line of code I'm using.

```
import DocViewer from "react-doc-viewer";
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How do I get my project to use that package?`?

Comment: What I mean is, it tells me the Package is installed, but when I try to execute the project, it fails and says { [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "react-doc-viewer" from "src/App.jsx". Does the file exist? }

Comment: Since the packages name is `@chalkbooks/react-doc-viewer`, you should also import `@chalkbooks/react-doc-viewer`, not `react-doc-viewer`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.